# Using trait method in the class constructor

Tags: scala, class, constructor, traits

I have a trait and a class that extends the trait. I can use the methods from the trait as follows:

```
trait A {
  def a = ""
}

class B(s: String) extends A {
  def b = a 
}
```

However, when I use the trait's method in the constructor like this:

```
trait A {
  def a = ""
}

class B(s: String) extends A {
  def this() = this(a) 
}
```

then the following error appears:

```
error: not found: value a
```

Is there some way to define default parameters for the construction of classes in the trait?

**EDIT:** To clarify the purpose: There is the akka-testkit:

```
class TestKit(_system: ActorSystem) extends { implicit val system = _system }
```

And each test looks like this:

```
class B(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system) with A with ... {
  def this() = this(actorSystem)
  ...
}
```

because I want to create common creation of the ActorSystem in A:

```
trait A {
  val conf = ...
  def actorSystem = ActorSystem("MySpec", conf)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you can have a constructor parameter that depends on a class member. The class member could (and usually does?) depend on the constructor parameters, which would allow for circular referencing. So `def a` isn't yet initialized.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bit tricky because of Scala initialization order. The simplest solution I found is to define a companion object for your class B with *apply* as factory method:

```
trait A {
  def a = "aaaa"
}

class B(s: String) {
 println(s)
}

object B extends A {
  def apply() = new B(a)
  def apply(s: String) = new B(s)
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the problem is, that B is called like `new B()` (it's in a generated code so I cannot modify it)